# Constructor with many parameters

Tags: java, constructor, instantiation

I have a class with (say) 50 fields.  I only use a few of them per deployment of the program per user need. Is there a way to make the constructor generic yet specific to the deployment?

e.g

```
public class Employee{

    private String id       = "default";
    private String empcat   = "default";
    private String empfam   = "default";
    private String phychar  = "default";
    private String othchar  = "default";
    private String shoesty  = "default";
    private Double shoesiz  = 0.0;
    private String shoesty  = "default";
    private Double shirsiz  = 0.0;
    private String shirsty  = "default";
    .........50 other fields..
}
```

"User/Customer 1" - only wants to use the program for shoe and thus instantiates the object with :
Employee obemp = new Employee("John", 11.5, Dockers); (i.e. id, shoesiz and shoesty)

User/Customer 2 - only wants to use the program for shirt and thus instantiates the object with :
Employee obemp = new Employee("John", 42, ABC); (i.e. id, shirsiz and shirsty)

User/Customer 3 - only wants to use the program for family and thus instantiates the object with :
Employee obemp = new Employee("John", "Smith"); (i.e. id, empfam)

The order of the fields during the object creation can be different - depending on the usage in the model.

Comment: OK, I see your question now.  Can you give an example of what "generic yet specific" means?  I'm not sure what you want.  Look at the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Comment: A better approach here would be Builder pattern, like `Employee e = Employee.ofName("John").ofSurname("Smith").build()`

Comment: Not to mention that this is object oriented programming. Shoe is one kind of object, shirt another, and so on.

Comment: Can I suggest that 50 fields in a single class might be too many - consider splitting it into smaller, more focussed classes, which you compose into an `Employee`.

Comment: why you not use an array like  public Employee(array) and and the user can pass the parameters he wants the other to be null or empty and that's it.... (i know it's not so easy but it is  a solution)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have looked into Builder pattern and it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest breaking your main class down into smaller pieces that manage data which typically goes together (Shoe information, Shirt information, Family information, etc.).

Secondly, I'd suggest you provide customers with a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java_Example) to make it easy for them to construct an object with just the pieces that they're likely to need. That way, they can do something like this:

```
Employee emp = new EmployeeBuilder("John")
    .withShirtInfo(shirsiz, shirsty)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic way in core java to do this. But you may use some design pattern like - builder pattern.

You may also create an `Employee` with some minimum criteria like - `id`. We can assume each `Employee` have an `id`. So create an `Employee` with the `id` using the `Employee(String id)` constructor -

```
public class Employee{

     //all properties

   public Employee(String id){
      this.id = id;
   }

   //setter methods
}
```

Suppose you have create an `Employee` like this -

```
Employee employee = new Employee("eng134");
```

After that you can set only required property to `employee` object using the setter methods -

```
employee.setShoesiz(9);
employee.setShirsiz(26);
```